# Qt 5.7 adding -std=gnu++11 to my compiler flags, clobbering -std=c++14

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, cmake, c++14

I am setting the following flags in my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -g -O0")
```

I am then using `find_package` to locate `Qt5Test`

```
find_package(Qt5Test REQUIRED)
```

I am then creating a [Model Test](https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test) library

```
add_library          (modeltest STATIC ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(modeltest Qt5::Test)
```

For some reason I'm getting `-fPIC -std=gnu++11` added to my compiler flags

```
CMakeFiles/modeltest.dir/flags.make:CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++14 -g -O0 -fPIC -std=gnu++11
```

This is clobbering my `-std=c++14` flag, causing all the c++14 features in my program to end up as compiler errors:

```
error: ‘foo’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type
constexpr auto foo()
                   ^
note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
```

- Is there a way to fix this?
- I'm using the latest version of Qt 5.7 downloaded from their site today

Comment: Of course there is "*a way to fix this*" - in the extreme case you could compile every object file by hand using the right flags. The question ought to be "*what* is the way to fix this". I (unfortunately) don't know the answer, but it must lie somewhere within your build system and how you aggregate compiler arguments..

Comment: @skypjack Ah! That definitely rings a bell! I'm not at my computer at the moment, but will try it out and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` explicitly.
Use this instead:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

This will definitely set the standard to be used for each *target*.

---

As suggested in the comments, the following should be considered too:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

See [this](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/) link for further details.
Thanks to @CraigScott for that pointed it out.

---

As mentioned in the comments by @wasthishelpful, properties [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html), [`CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html) and [`CXX_EXTENSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html) can also be used for a per-target configuration.
See the links above for further details.

Comment: You should also set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` and `CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS`. See [this article](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/) for why.

Comment: Just to mention, properties [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html), [`CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html) and [`CXX_EXTENSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html) can also be used for a *per-target* configuration

Comment: I am having a similar problem using Clang in QtCreator using Qt 5.10. With my Clang builds, the "-std=gnu++11" flag is set, which overrides the "-std=c++17" flag that is set because of the line in my .pro file: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17...

Does QtCreator generate a CMake file somewhere?

Comment: @IronAttorney Nope.

Comment: I've found a makefile, generated by qmake. It lists the flags including the imposter gnu++11 flag... I can delete it, but of course, when I try and build again, QMake regenerates the makefile, bad flags and all...