# Linking with cmake, icc and pthreads (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, libraries, icc

I am trying to compile a simple test project with the `Intel C++ Compiler`, `CMake`, and `std::threads` support.

If I do :

```
icpc -std=c++11 -lpthread source/main.cpp
```

Then the build and the program work fine.

But with `CMake` I get an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "test" which is not built by
  this project.
```

`CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
project(test)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_LIST "source/main.cpp")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_LIST})
```

I am building in an environment set by the script supplied by `icc` (`compilervars.sh`) and `CMake` is called with the `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc` options. It works if I'm not using threads.

What is wrong with my use of `CMake`?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to first declare the executable and then set the link libraries, otherwise `target_link_libraries` does not know about the executable (`test` in your case) and complaints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking back the documentation for [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), a target must be declared **before** being used:

> The named `<target>` must **have been created** in the current directory by a command such as [`add_executable()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html#command:add_executable) or [`add_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#command:add_library).

BTW as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40798768/6612932), you should not set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` explicitly, and prefer setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and related variables:

```
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(SOURCE_LIST "source/main.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_LIST})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
```

Comment: Thanks. The CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD flags do not work with the Intel Compiler with CMake 3.5 or below, and on the distribution I'm using CMake is 3.5.1

Answer (score 2):

The order is wrong: first declare your executable and let CMake know that it exists

```
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_LIST})
```

and afterwards add the link libraries

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
```

From [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)'s documentation:

> The named  must have been created in the current directory by a command such as add_executable() or add_library()